# Trouble when adding actionListener() to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add actionListener to a JPanel in swing frame.
I want to create an event when clicking on that particular JPanel.
Here is some slice of code where in stuck down.

```
JLabel jlab=new JLabel("");
JPanel pnl=new JPanel();
pnl.add(jlab);
JPanel mainpnl=new JPanel();
pnl.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)      {jlab.setText("Clciking !!!");}});
mainpnl.add(pnl);
```

Comment: Thank you "MadProgrammer" for editing.I am bit new to StackOverflow's text editor!!

Comment: Thanks for that !!!But for "MouseListener",I would have to implement MouseMotionListener.But I dont want to do so because it is not full filling some of my needs.

Comment: No, for `MouseListener` you have to implement `MouseListener` and nothing else. Don’t look for things having almost similar names. Look for the thing that was named.

Answer (score 1):

`JPanel` doesn't have the capabilities to raise `ActionEvent`s, thus it does not have the method `addActionListener`.

Instead, you probably want to use a `MouseListener` instead

Check out [How to write mouse listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details...